# Show there is exactly one path $g:[0, 1]\rightarrow E$ such that $p◦g = f$ and $g(0) = e.$

Tags: general-topology

The question is:

Suppose $p : (E, τ ) \rightarrow (B, σ)$ is a covering map, $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow B$ is a path in B with starting point $b = f(0)$, $e$ is a point in $E$ with $p(e) = b$, and $f([0,1])$ is contained in some $\sigma$-open $U$ which is evenly covered by p.

Show there is exactly one path $g:[0, 1]\rightarrow E$ such that $p◦g = f$ and $g(0) = e.$

I am having trouble intuitively understanding what's going on in this setup. Are we trying to prove that there is a unique path $g$ in $E$ that "is equivalent" to $f$ in $B$ through the covering map $p$?

I am stuck on how to explore the fact that $f([0,1])$ is contained in an evenly covered open set to formalize these ideas (if they are correct at all).

Comment: Intuitively, the inverse image $p^{-1}(U)$ is a bunch of disjoint sets $V_j$ that are each homeomorphic to $U$ under the covering map (this is what "$U$ is evenly covered by $p$" means, I believe). In each of these $V_j$, there is a homeomorphic copy of the path $f$ that gets projected to $f$ under $p$. But since you are fixing a basepoint $e$, that uniquely determines one of the $V_j$ and hence one of the homeomorphic copies of $f$ --- namely, the one contained in the $V_j$ that contains $e$.

Comment: What you ask is a well-known property of covering projections (unique path lifting). You will find a proof in any book dealing with covering projections. $f([0,1])$ is not necessarily contained in an evenly covered open set, but you can diívide $[0,1]$ into subintervals having this property.